# PostgreSQL Json Syntax

Tags: json, postgresql, visual-studio

I use this function to monitor changes to the database.

```
CREATE FUNCTION public.NotifyOnDataChange()
RETURNS trigger
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS $BODY$ 
DECLARE
    data JSON;
    notification JSON;
BEGIN
-- if we delete, then pass the old data
-- if we insert or update, pass the new data
IF (TG_OP = 'DELETE') THEN
    data = row_to_json(OLD);
ELSE
    data = row_to_json(NEW);
END IF;

-- create json payload
-- note that here can be done projection 
notification = json_build_object(
        'table',TG_TABLE_NAME,
        'action', TG_OP, -- can have value of INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
        'data', data);  
        
-- note that channel name MUST be lowercase, otherwise pg_notify() won't work
PERFORM pg_notify('datachange', notification::TEXT);
RETURN NEW;
END
$BODY$;
```

The Result looks like this:

```
"{""table"" : ""um_user"", ""action"" : ""INSERT"", ""data"" : {""id"":5,""name"":""Marc"",""number"":25,""icon"":8,""admin"":false}}"
```

I wonder why they put double quotation marks. According to https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com these are not a valid format.

Comment: [Doubling quotes is what postgres uses for escaping](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-syntax-lexical.html), however for identifier names not for string values. Where exactly did you get that text, how did you print it?

Comment: I can't replicate: ```select (json_build_object('data',row_to_json(row('test', 1, 'f'))))::text;  {"data" : {"f1":"test","f2":1,"f3":"f"}}```. It must be something  ```pg_notify``` is doing.

Comment: @Bergi I get this result from a NpgsqlConnection in Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: @hilrol Sounds like a bug in that tool, I'd report it. Both channel and payload should be formatted as values of type `text`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shame on me.

I found out that VisualStudio displays these double quotes when the mouse is over the value.

[image]

In Quick View everything is ok, no double quotes!

[image]

I have been using Visual Studio as a hobby for years but I have never noticed that before.